# Upgrade GNU parted 3.1 to 3.2

Tags: linux, upgrade, key-authentication, gnu, parted

I'm trying to upgrade GNU parted 3.1 to 3.2 and when I try to verify the key it says :

```
#  gpg --verify parted-3.2.tar.xz.sig
gpg: Signature made Mon 28 Jul 2014 11:20:50 PM EDT using RSA key ID 3348AAF0
gpg: Good signature from "Phillip Susi <psusi@ubuntu.com>"
gpg:                 aka "Phillip Susi <psusi@cfl.rr.com>"
gpg: Note: This key has expired!
Primary key fingerprint: 1B49 F933 916A 37A3 F45A  1812 015F 4DD4 A70F B705
     Subkey fingerprint: E9CD C6E7 010A 6386 A734  951E 8E45 A022 3348 AAF0
```

it didn't upgrade yet and I'm still on 3.1 ... 
I don't know which key is expired !

I renewed the key that `GNU` provided :

```
 gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 8E45A0223348AAF0
```

But nothing change!

Comment: What distribution are you using? And why don't you use your distribution's binary package?

Comment: I'm using CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 ... how can I use my " distribution's binary package " ?

Comment: `yum install parted`.

Comment: Check what versions of parted are available for your distribution, to start with.

Comment: @jordanm ... When I try to install it says : Package parted-3.1-23.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version . It's weird, I'm sure that I installed 3.2 ! ....

Comment: @Faheem Mitha ... How can I check ?

Comment: @zobra what does 3.2 have that you need?

Comment: Well it's for ( resize ) command which is not available in 3.1

Comment: @Zorba Sorry, I don't use RH systems enough to be able to give you any useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the key's details (using `gpg --edit-key 0x8E45A0223348AAF0`) shows the following:

```
pub  rsa2048/0x015F4DD4A70FB705
     created: 2011-12-13  expires: never       usage: SCA 
     trust: unknown       validity: unknown
sub  rsa2048/0xD1FDDE0451FEF1C9
     created: 2011-12-13  expired: 2013-12-13  usage: E   
sub  rsa2048/0x9AC13A54FA9EEEF9
     created: 2011-12-14  expired: 2013-12-13  usage: S   
sub  rsa2048/0x8E45A0223348AAF0
     created: 2013-11-26  expired: 2014-11-26  usage: S   
sub  rsa2048/0x1B6CD765BDCC7F92
     created: 2013-11-26  expired: 2014-11-26  usage: E   
sub  rsa2048/0xD455AF0D9C8E5E51
     created: 2014-10-29  expired: 2015-10-29  usage: S   
sub  rsa2048/0xBF0C615393A02CCD
     created: 2014-10-29  expired: 2015-10-29  usage: E   
sub  rsa2048/0x107951615CBBA516
     created: 2015-10-05  expires: 2016-09-29  usage: S   
sub  rsa2048/0xEBD87E9510850B71
     created: 2015-10-05  expires: 2016-09-29  usage: E   
[ unknown] (1). Phillip Susi <psusi@ubuntu.com>
[ unknown] (2)  Phillip Susi <psusi@cfl.rr.com>
```

`parted-3.2.tar.xz` was signed with subkey `0x8E45A0223348AAF0` which expired in November 2014. The tarball was released in July 2014 so the subkey used was valid at the time of signature, so the fact that the subkey has since expired isn't a cause for concern.

Unless you'd pinned the key previously, since it's not part of the strong set there's not much more that can be said.

Comment: Thank you for the info ... So there was no possibility to upgrade to 3.2 after November 2014, as long as GNU didn't upgrade the subkey since that date ?!

Comment: You can upgrade, `gpg` is telling you that the subkey expired but that doesn't negate the value of the signature...

Comment: Should I upgrade ( gpg ) to make sure the value works ?

Comment: It's already working, `gpg` tells you `gpg: Good signature from "Phillip Susi <psusi@ubuntu.com>"` which means the signature is OK. There's no need to upgrade `gpg`, newer versions will say exactly the same thing.

Comment: I see ... so there is no way to upgrade to parted 2.3 at this time

Comment: Yes, there is, just extract the tarball and build and install it!